# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'TryParse'

Tags: c#, .net, string, compiler-errors, tryparse

Having a little trouble working this one out, I'm wanting to store up to 50 movies in an array in order and allow them to be deleted/searched by users.

However it's giving me errors saying that the parseAttempt does not exist and 'string' does not contain a definition for 'TryParse'...

Here's everything that I've got so far, if it'll help makes things clearer. - http://pastebin.com/V4aAAPf5

```
// Movie Title
parseAttempt = false;
while (parseAttempt == false)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the movie title >");
    vTemp = Console.ReadLine();
    Attempt = string.TryParse(vTemp, out movie_title[current_movie]);                    
    // Check data valid
    // Check constraints
    if (movie_title[current_movie] <= 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Movie title must be > 0");
        parseAttempt = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: So are you 'trying' to 'parse' as string to get its string representation?

Comment: You seem confused about the meaning of Parse...

Comment: what is movie_title defined as?

Comment: Also, if movie title must be larger than 0, how are you going to store [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397313/) ?

Answer (score 6):

`TryParse` is not a member of `System.String` class. Basically `TryParse` or `Parse` methods are used to parse "string" datavalue into primitive types - int, float etc.

Remove this `Attempt = string.TryParse(vTemp, out movie_title[current_movie]);`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `movie_title[]` is some sort of array of a numeric type. If it's an array of `int`, then

`Attempt = int.TryParse(vTemp, out movie_title[current_movie]);`

should work.